# XNA Content isn't unloading disposable assets (Texture2D)

Tags: c#, xna, textures

The game that I'm working on loads all textures from a folder in the Content sub-project and stores them in a `Texture2D[]`.

For reasons that I cannot figure out, it appears as if the ContentManager (Content) for XNA never unloads these textures, ever. So even if I delete them from the folder, they're still stored in the pipeline.

Here is my Content folder:

[image]

And here is the ContentManager's loadedAssets in debug.

[image]

As you can see from the elements outlines in red, those textures have been deleted from the Content folder but they persist in the ContentManager cache. This means that when I load all textures from the "TileSets" folder, the supposedly deleted textures get loaded in as well.

I've tried `Content.Dispose()` and `Content.Unload()` in my main `UnloadContent()` but those don't fix the problem. Also made sure that the textures were deleted from the folder in my external folder explorer and even checked ContentPipeline.xml; the textures are not referenced there.

What's going on? Am I missing something?

Comment: Also, if anyone thinks this would be better suited for GameDev, I'll happily move it there. I just figured that it's more of a programming question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently I had missed the .xnb files, which are stored in `~\bin\x86\Debug\Content`.

After deleting the files from there, everything worked as expected.

Comment: It's nice you could figure it out yourself :)